# Cannot connect to MS-SQL with react-native

Tags: sql-server, typescript, react-native

I have used the following package
import MSSQL from 'react-native-mssql';

near the above package on hover, it shows 
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-mssql'. 'd:/React Native Apps/Login/node_modules/react-native-mssql/index.android.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-mssql` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-mssql';`
module "d:/React Native Apps/Login/node_modules/react-native-mssql/index.android

I have tried installing as mentioned above but nothing works.

And in code, I am getting an error at below line. 
MSSQL.connect(config);

error is following
undeined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeMssql2.default.connect')

Please tell me how do I connect to MSSQL with react-native.

Comment: did you've the last version of react-native? Because seems a react-native source code bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-native-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mssql) can be installed with `npm install --save react-native-mssql`

then edit file `android/settings.gradle` and add:

```
include ':react-native-mssql'
project(':react-native-mssql').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mssql/android')
```

as well as file `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':react-native-mssql')
}
```

then it can be added to the packages list:

```
...
import com.stonem.mssql.MSSQLPackage;

...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        ...
        .addPackage(new MSSQLPackage())
        ...
    );
}
```

and then connected:

```
import MSSQL from 'react-native-mssql';
...

let config = {
    server: '192.168.1.1', // ip address of the mssql database
    username: 'sa',        // username to login to the database
    password: 'password',  // password to login to the database
    database: 'admin',     // the name of the database to connect to
    port: 1234             // OPTIONAL, port of the database on the server
}
MSSQL.connect(config);
```

an example for a `SELECT` query:

```
let query = 'SELECT TOP * FROM USERS'
MSSQL.executeQuery(query);
```

and one for an `UPDATE` query:

```
let query = 'UPDATE USERS SET Active=0'
MSSQL.executeUpdate(query);
```

make sure to call `MSSQL.close();` once the connection isn't required anymore.

Comment: how to implement above code in React-Native , app.js file. Plz Help to understand above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "**react-native link react-native-mssql**" in the command prompt after using "cd **Project_Name**" to fix the issue, if  ***'Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-mssql'*** was your issue all along.